# App Store Submission tvOS Bundle Identifier

Tags: swift, xcode7, tvos, bundle-identifier, xcode7.1beta

I am trying to upload a tvOS app as a target from my iOS app however I am not sure what the bundle identifier should be? Should it be the same as the iOS app or `com.mywebsite.myapp.tvosapp` or something different?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple [suggests](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Submission%20Process#85768189) you to attach tvOS app to iOS app.

This requires to use the same bundle ID with your iOS app.

Comment: just a not you need to set the bundle id in info.plist file. if you use General tab for target then bundle id does not get set properly

Comment: @Developer the identifier should fill in to the plist from what you put in the general tab if the identifier in the plist is set to `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`

Comment: "To distribute your iOS app and tvOS app together with a universal purchase, both apps need to use the same app record in iTunes Connect. You can create a new app for both iOS and tvOS using the same app record or add a platform to your existing app record. The iOS app and tvOS app share the same bundle ID but must have their own version in the app record and must be uploaded separately. The iOS app and tvOS app may have different version numbers and build strings."